# Post Rsync Migration Apt Not Recognizing Installed Packages

Tags: apt, package-management, php, rsync

My server was recently migrated via `rsync`, while everything appears to work correctly `apt` doesn't recognize the existence of some packages and services.

**Question:**
Is there a way to '*refresh*' apt so that it will recognize all packages and services currently on the server?

**Example of the problem**
This shows php7.4-fpm is installed and currently running

```
root@admin:~# service php7.4-fpm status
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-21 20:10:25 CST; 20h ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 1339 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/php/php-fpm.so>
   Main PID: 915 (php-fpm7.4)
     Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 1236, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4612)
     Memory: 3.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/php7.4-fpm.service
             ├─ 915 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
             ├─1326 php-fpm: pool www
             └─1327 php-fpm: pool www
```

**Whereas** this shows apt doesn't recognize the php7.4 package (same is true for apache, mysql, etc.)

```
root@admin:/etc/apt# apt remove php7.4-fpm 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php7.4-fpm' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Assistance appreciated

**Solutions that I have tried**

```
#rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
#rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
#rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
#dpkg --configure -a
#apt clean
#apt update --fix-missing
#apt install -f
#dpkg --configure -a
#apt upgrade
#reboot
```

Literally, everything is functioning properly.. only `apt` doesn't recognize that my packages exist.

Comment: Did you do `apt update` first of all?

Comment: Yes... and more... I will edit the post... now